# How to get the img src value from raw content in haml (Rails )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

How can i get the img src value from the (= raw post.body) in ruby on rails haml page ? Now i am getting the total contents i.e,

```
<p>Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum</p>\r\n<p><img style=\"float: right;\" src=\"../../../spree/blog_entry_images/704/large/IMG_4378.jpg?1466600823\" alt=\"\" width=\"404\" height=\"606\" /><img src=\"../../../spree/blog_entry_images/718/large/IMG_4356.jpg?1466608157\" alt=\"\" width=\"405\" height=\"608\" /></p>
```

I want to show each image in loop. So how can i get this ???

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you want to show just images present in that raw post body or whole body content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [gem nokogiri](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri) to extract any html tag, try following code snippet, you might need to `require 'nokogiri'` while try on `console`

```
 content = Nokogiri::HTML(pass_your_html_content)
 srcs    = content.css('img').map{ |i| i['src'] }
```

Comment: Thank you @Rokibul